# Can I copy $ so that it always uses a context when creating jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to incorporate a little canvas app I built into a huge mess of a Sharepoint site where I do not have any control over anything, everything. The app will go into a "WebPart" wrapper `div`. To keep things nice and tidy in my JS I was thinking I could a cloned version of jQuery that always uses my wrapper object as context so that I can be sure I'll never select and alter anything outside of my wrapper like:

```
var ctxed$ = ctxjQuery('#wrapper-el'); //this is what I don't get

(function($){
   $('p').addClass('awesome'); //should only affect elements inside #wrapper-el
})(ctxed$)
```

Anyhow, things I tried did not work out. I tried using `$.proxy` which did not work as I expected (as context is a different thing here...).

This is the point where I am stuck at the moment:

```
function getContextifiedjQuery(ctx) {

    var fn = function () {

        return $.call(arguments[0], ctx);
    }

    $.each($, function (k, v) {
        fn[k] = v;
    });

    return fn;

}

var wrapper$ = getContextifiedjQuery('#wrapper');

wrapper$('p').css('color', 'red');
wrapper$.each([1, 2, 3], function () {
    alert(this)
});
```

which works as a simple test case, yet when I try to use it in my project I get circular references and things go awry. What is it that I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing with `$("p")` is basically

```
ctxjQuery('#wrapper-el')('p')
```

If you want to work off the context it would be

```
(function($){
   $.find('p').addClass('awesome'); //should only affect elements inside #wrapper-el
})(ctxed$)
```

If you want to write the wrapper, it would look something like this, but it will only support find(). It will override everything else.

```
function ctxjQuery(context) {
    return function (selector) {
        return $(context).find(selector);
    }
}

var ctxed$ = ctxjQuery('#wrapper-el'); //this is what I don't get

(function ($) {
    $('p').addClass('awesome'); //should only affect elements inside #wrapper-el
})(ctxed$)
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpGv2/)

and thinking about it again, you can do something like this:

```
function ctxjQuery(context) {
    var fnc = function(selector){  return $(context).find(selector); };
    var $Fnc = $.extend( fnc, $);
    return $Fnc;    
}

var ctxed$ = ctxjQuery('#wrapper-el'); //this is what I don't get

(function ($) {
    console.log($.each);
    $('p').addClass('awesome'); //should only affect elements inside #wrapper-el
})(ctxed$)
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpGv2/1/)

It will break a lot of stuff!!! Example `$("<p/>")` will not create an element since it is overloaded with find(). Basically you would need to recreate the jQuery core function to get all the functionality!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but could I also apply this to my situation where I would favor not altering the code inside the closure?

Comment: @m90 Updated my answer to show you how you could make your idea work, but it will override everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I finally get your answer now :) The find would be ok, the only thing "missing" would be `$.each`, could I copy that like in my initial approach then (iterate over $ and copy the contents)? See: http://jsfiddle.net/SpGv2/2/

Comment: `extend` looks smart! Should have thought of that myself.

Comment: I edited it right after you posted this to include the $.each, but you will be breaking other stuff my my post says.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Thanks for answer / clarification / explanation in any case!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var ctxed$ = function (selector)
{
    return $(selector, '#wrapper-el');
}
(function($){
   $('p').addClass('awesome'); //should only affect elements inside #wrapper-el
})(ctxed$);
```